# Displaying Image from firebase cloud firestore in React Native with Image reference not working

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, image, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to access locally stored images with references stored in a firestore database. The second text line shows what I store in the firestore database. And when I put this text straight into an Image component it works and displays the image. However when referencing to the image using categories. The image I get a warning "Failed prop type:Invalid prop `source` supplied to `Image` and the Image isn't displayed

```js
import * as React from "react";
import {View, Text, Image} from "react-native";
import styles from "../../src/styles/MainStyle";
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {collection, getDocs} from "@firebase/firestore";
import {db} from "../../db/firebase-config";
import quizScreen from "../../src/styles/ScreenStyles/QuizScreen";

export default function Testread({navigation}) {
    const [categories,setCategories] = useState([]);
    const databaseCollectionRef = collection(db, "Categories")

    useEffect(() =>{
        const getCategories = async () => {

            const data = await getDocs(databaseCollectionRef)
            setCategories(data.docs.map((doc)=>({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})))

        }
        getCategories()
    }, [])
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>

            {categories.map((categories) => {return <View>
                <Text>Name:{categories.Title}</Text>
                <Image style={quizScreen.picture} source={categories.Image} />
                <Text>Image: {categories.Image}</Text>
            </View>})}
            <Image style={quizScreen.picture} source={require('../../assets/images/Geography.png')} />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Picture of the app when running :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might be passing undefined to Image source try using a condition at source to avoid passing undefined